# Question from SQL exam that I find hard to answer

Tags: sql, testing, relational-database

I had an exam from relational databases.
I had a question (translated from Polish) which I cannot find any clues to answer:
"What are the problems (three of them) of data deletion in presence of foreign key? 
What solutions are available?"
RD are my achilles' heel :(

Comment: I cannot think of specific "problems", only features of SQL that may or may not be appropriate in a given circumstance.  If these are interpreted as "problems", that would be a judgement made in the class.

Comment: What did you learn from, say, reading your textbook re deleting in DBMSs & SQL? See [ask], hits googling 'stackexchange homework' & the voting arrow mouseover texts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> What are the problems (three of them) of data deletion in presence of foreign key?

I would not call them problems but things to consider:

1) `TRUNCATE TABLE` does not work when FK is present(SQL Server)

2) You have to delete from referencing table first(if there is no CASCADE option defined)

3) Deletion could be slower if index is not present(checking  referential integrity on large table could be really slow)

Answer (score 1):

There are two scenarios:

### A) With ON DELETE CASCADE

1. You only want to delete a single record, but it takes awfully long, because its whole tree gets deleted.
2. You mistakenly delete one row, and oops, half of your database is gone.
3. You want to delete one row. The DBMS tries to remember all deletes that occur in consequence (in order to be able to rollback the actions) and runs out of memory in the process.

Solution: don't use `ON DELETE CASCADE`.

### B) Without ON DELETE CASCADE

1. You want to delete one row, but must manually delete its children first, and their children before that, etc.
2. So, in order to delete from a table, you must know all its children and grandchildren, i.e. the whole tree.
3. don't know

Solutions: Either use `ON DELETE CASCADE` or delete via dynamic SQL (read the system tables first, so you know the tree, then delete from bottom up).